# Article written "in" or "on" a journal?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is an article "written in a journal" or "written on a journal"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a journal. If you write on a journal it sounds as if you're writing on its cover.

Comment: Or about the journal.

Comment: @Wes - we can talk more about this conversation later. ;-)

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean exactly.

Comment: @Wes - The idea of writing about a journal reminded me of a joke, as in "I'd like to talk more about a conversation later."